# Is there any way to upload an image to a cell using Google Sheets API v4?

Tags: .net, file-upload, google-sheets-api

I am currently trying to figure out if it's possible or not to upload an image to google sheets using Google Sheets API v4. The only answer i found to this topic is to use an "=IMAGE" function, but it's not what i am looking for because it only works for URLs. Is there any way of doing it? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Can you add few clarifications to the question  1. Are you trying to upload an image to google sheets using the google sheets API from a .NET Client ? If so can you share the code. What is failing ? If you are not looking for uploading images from URL to google sheets what are you looking for ?

Comment: What about uploading your images to Drive and import them to Sheets?

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding. Yes, i want to upload an image from a .NET client, but i currently don't have any code for this just because i have no idea how to implement this. I am looking for a way to upload from user PC. Regarding the use of google drive for importing pictures, in the sheets' IMAGE function documentation (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=en) it says "You can only use URLs that aren't hosted at drive.google.com." so I'm assuming it's not really possible, but i haven't really try that.